# Can't boot to windows after removing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-7, removing

If this is not the right place, please tell me where to ask this.

I tried to remove ubuntu from windows, and I deleted the partitions. after starting up windows, I executed in command line: `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`, and expected to start windows normally, I didn't. When I restarted, It showed me something like "bad configuration booting", I don't really remember, and I don't have access to the error anymore, because I installed xubuntu. In the installation, xubuntu didn't recognized any OS on the computer, but I have access to data in windows.
currently, I'm trapped in xubuntu, which is a horrible thing, because I need windows really bad. I beg you to help me

Comment: This is not a community for Windows help. Those questions should be directed to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Start up your computer with the USB or DVD Windows 8 recovery media in the system.

When the computer boots off the recovery media, pick the Troubleshoot option.

Then choose Advanced Options.

and head on over to the Command Prompt.

The computer should reboot and then ask you for the account.

Click your account to continue.

Then login to get started.

We’re going to use the built in partitioning tool called diskpart to confirm that:

```
We have all the right partitions
EFI partition is formatted correctly.
```

In the black screen that looks like a dark abyss, type:

```
diskpart
```

and enter this command:

```
sel disk 0
```

Now that the first disk is selected we need to view all the partitions

```
list vol
```

Verify that the EFI partition is using the FAT32 file system then select the volume and assign a drive letter to it.

Let’s say your EFI partition is on Volume 3, the next thing you would type is:

```
sel vol 3
```

Then assign an arbitrary drive letter to the parition. Let’s use v.

```
assign letter=v:
```

You should see a message saying: DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point.

Exit the diskpart tool by typing:

```
exit
```

You should still be in the command prompt but outside of the DISKPART> prompt.

We need to repair the boot record. We can pull that off like so:

```
cd /d v:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\

bootrec /fixboot
```

The CD command tells the command line interpreter to change the directory to the volume label that has the EFI boot record.

Then the bootrec /fixboot command attempts to repair the selected volume.

Now we need to recreate the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store, so let’s backup the existing store first

Type:

```
ren BCD BCD.old
```

Now that we backed it up, let’s recreate the BCD store:

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s v: /f ALL
```

Now remove the recovery media and reboot and you should be all set.

Source: windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-recovery-overview

Comment: This appears to be plagiarized from http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/. Deleting.

Comment: Ah, I see now you have sourced this one, however it doesn't match the link you provide, but it does match the one I found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already deleted all partitions related to Ubuntu (including grub). You will need to boot the computer with a Windows recovery USB. After booting with the USB you can follow the attached guide (Link 1) to help you in fixing the boot process. Hope that helps fix your problem. Also, next time please look in a Windows related source for Windows problems.

**NOTE** If you do not have a recovery USB check out method 6 in the second link. It will help you get to the advanced start up menu and then from there go back to the guide in link one. After regaining access to Windows consider making a permanent Windows recovery USB.

Link 1: http://www.techspot.com/guides/630-windows-8-boot-fix/

Link 2: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm